# How to prevent dict.update(new_dict) from adding empty data?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's say I have a dictionary defined as:

```
dict_1['x']['y'] = 'something'
```

And another dictionary defined as:

```
dict_2['x'] = {}

dict_2['x']['z'] = 'something else'
```

How can I make it so that

`dict_1.update(dict_2)` only adds the `dict_2['x']['z'] = 'something else'` but doesn't `delete dict_1['x']['y']` because of the `dict_2['x'] = {}.`

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_1['x'].update(dict_2['x'])
```

Comment: maybe an easier way? that would be very exhaustive in my code

Comment: is it because your dict_1 has multiple keys?

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: i think his answer was just fine personally. yes my dict_1 has tons of nested keys.

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem recursively.

```
def mergeDicts(dict1, dict2):
    for key in dict2:
        if key in dict1:
            dict1[key] = mergeDicts(dict1[key], dict2[key])
        else:
            dict1[key] = dict2[key]
    return dict1
```